# When using Symfony Forms, how to render inputs for one entity type but with multiple input types

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I am having a hard time making a form to edit a already existing subset of the Entity "Setting".
The idea is to render only a determined collection of "Settings" in one template, each with his custom input type, at least on template level changing the widget.

The Setting Entity looks like this:

App\Entity\Setting.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SettingRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Ulid;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SettingRepository::class)]
class Setting
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'ulid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.ulid_generator')]
    private ?Ulid $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $slug = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $value = null;

    public function getId(): ?Ulid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(?string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Form Type:

App\Form\SettingGeneralType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Setting;
use App\Form\SettingType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SettingGeneralType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('value')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Setting::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

For the "Set" that needs to be in the form i could give following data:

| id | name | value | slug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | App name | AppName | app_name |
|  | App logo | NULL | app_logo |
|  | App description | NULL | app_description |
|  | Maintenance mode | false | app_maintenance |
|  | Default date and time format | d.m.Y H:i | app_datetime_format |
|  | PHP bin path | pathToPhp.bin | app_php_bin_path |
|  | Default color mode | auto | app_theme_default |

The value types vary between string,choice (Dropdowns),boolean (checkboxes).

I would have no problem in formatting the different form widgets manually in the template to fit the required value, but i can't find any solution to how to render only a little collection each with his own "input" from this entity.

My only idea was using the "CollectionType" since it can render a set of simple forms i can render in the template and handle on submit, but i could not get it to filter entites that i wanted be rendered in those forms since i dont want every setting to be rendered...

This is my first question, so no hate if i missed something please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello what you're trying to do is called Embded Forms, to achieve what you need you have to create a custom FormType with inputs you need then you can use that custom formType in you formBuilder check documentation here for normal forms [check here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html#embedding-a-collection-of-forms)  and here for Embded Collection form [check here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

your code must look something like :

```
class CustomType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
     {
         $builder->add('name')
                 ->add('description');
     }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
      {
          $resolver->setDefaults([
          'data_class' => Custom::class,
      ]);
   }
}
```

And then in your builder use customType :

```
$builder->add('settings', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => CustomType::class,
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is what i'm trying to acomplish but how do i tell from the "parent" for to the embedded form what entity to use/render. Since i want it to render only a few settings for example.

Comment: i dont really understand what you mean , but if you're talking about configureOptions if you don't have entity and the fields are just custom you can make the data_class => null in your custom FormType . if you can explain a bit more I might be able to help you

Comment: Sure, my problem isn't the class itself but how to tell which/how many entites shall be embedded. For example I have the entities in the table above, i want each of them with an embedded form, basically which Entities are in the Collection.

Comment: I thinking in create a new class Attribute, something like #[ClassConfigurable], asign to all class that you need, and use PropertyInfo component to get needed class and related attributes info to create embedbed collection form type.